# How can I retrieve string literals using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, string, reflection, literals

Is it possible to retreive all of the string literal values from an assembly using reflection?

Lets say I have this class:

```
public class Example
{
    public void PrintName()
    {
        Debug.Print(@"My name is Dave");
    }
}
```

I would like to use reflection to get a list of strings in the application like the string "My name is Dave".

I have found how to do this if the string is assigned to a variable, but not for an inline literal.

Comment: I never heared of reflection being able to inspect method bodies (except maybe extract the raw IL bytes), so might not be possible.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. You would have to parse the code. Look into [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).

Comment: AFAIK Reflection can't do what you ask...

Comment: Is there any way to get a hold of the string intern set, or is that entirely hidden from us?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is some quick code that should work.  Another thing you can do is read all the string literals in an assembly by looking at the #US metadata stream.  I wrote some code a while back that does this I can dig up if you are interested.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (string literal in FindLiterals(typeof(Program).GetMethod("TestMethod1", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(literal);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static IEnumerable<string> FindLiterals(MethodInfo method)
        {
            ILReader reader = new ILReader(method);
            foreach (ILInstruction instruction in reader.Instructions)
            {
                if (instruction.Op == OpCodes.Ldstr)
                {
                    yield return instruction.Data as string;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void TestMethod1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Abc");
            Console.WriteLine("123");
        }
    }

    public interface IILReaderProvider
    {
        byte[] GetMethodBody();

        FieldInfo ResolveField(int metadataToken);
        MemberInfo ResolveMember(int metadataToken);

        MethodBase ResolveMethod(int metadataToken);
        byte[] ResolveSignature(int metadataToken);

        string ResolveString(int metadataToken);
        Type ResolveType(int metadataToken);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ILInstruction
    {
        private readonly OpCode operationCode; // 40.  56-64.  The entire structure is very big.  maybe do array lookup for opcode instead.

        private readonly byte[] instructionRawData;

        private readonly object instructionData;

        private readonly int instructionAddress;

        private readonly int index;

        internal ILInstruction(OpCode code, byte[] instructionRawData, int instructionAddress, object instructionData, int index)
        {
            this.operationCode = code;
            this.instructionRawData = instructionRawData;
            this.instructionAddress = instructionAddress;
            this.instructionData = instructionData;
            this.index = index;
        }

        public OpCode Op
        {
            get
            {
                return this.operationCode;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the raw data.
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] RawData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.instructionRawData;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the data.
        /// </summary>
        public object Data
        {
            get
            {
                return this.instructionData;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the address of the instruction.
        /// </summary>
        public int Address
        {
            get
            {
                return this.instructionAddress;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the index of the instruction.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The index of the instruction.
        /// </value>
        public int InstructionIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value as integer
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The data value.</value>
        public int DataValue
        {
            get
            {
                int value = 0;
                if (this.Data != null)
                {
                    if (this.Data is byte)
                    {
                        value = (byte)this.Data;
                    }
                    else if (this.Data is short)
                    {
                        value = (short)this.Data;
                    }
                    else if (this.Data is int)
                    {
                        value = (int)this.Data;
                    }
                }

                return value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the length of the instructions and operands.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The length.</value>
        public int Length
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Op.Size + (this.RawData == null ? 0 : this.RawData.Length);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
        /// </returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.AppendFormat("0x{0:x4} {1,-10}", this.Address, this.Op.Name);

            if (this.Data != null)
            {
                builder.Append(this.Data.ToString());
            }

            if (this.RawData != null && this.RawData.Length > 0)
            {
                builder.Append(" [0x");
                for (int i = this.RawData.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    builder.Append(this.RawData[i].ToString("x2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }

                builder.Append(']');
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads IL instructions from a byte stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Allows generated code to be viewed without debugger or enabled debug assemblies.</remarks>
    public sealed class ILReader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The _instruction lookup.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly Lazy<Dictionary<short, OpCode>> instructionLookup = new Lazy<Dictionary<short, OpCode>>(ILReader.GetLookupTable, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

        /// <summary>
        /// The IL reader provider.
        /// </summary>
        private IILReaderProvider intermediateLanguageProvider;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ILReader"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method">
        /// The method.
        /// </param>
        public ILReader(MethodInfo method)
        {
            if (method == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
            }

            this.intermediateLanguageProvider = ILReader.CreateILReaderProvider(method);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the instructions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The instructions.</value>
        public IEnumerable<ILInstruction> Instructions
        {
            get
            {
                byte[] instructionBytes = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.GetMethodBody();
                int instructionIndex = 0, startAddress;
                for (int position = 0; position < instructionBytes.Length; )
                {
                    startAddress = position;
                    short operationData = instructionBytes[position];
                    if (IsInstructionPrefix(operationData))
                    {
                        operationData = (short)((operationData << 8) | instructionBytes[++position]);
                    }

                    position++;

                    OpCode code;
                    if (!instructionLookup.Value.TryGetValue(operationData, out code))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidProgramException(string.Format("0x{0:X2} is not a valid op code.", operationData));
                    }

                    int dataSize = GetSize(code.OperandType);
                    byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(instructionBytes, position, data, 0, dataSize);
                    object objData = this.GetData(code, data);
                    position += dataSize;

                    if (code.OperandType == OperandType.InlineSwitch)
                    {
                        dataSize = (int)objData;
                        int[] labels = new int[dataSize];
                        for (int index = 0; index < labels.Length; index++)
                        {
                            labels[index] = BitConverter.ToInt32(instructionBytes, position);
                            position += 4;
                        }

                        objData = labels;
                    }

                    yield return new ILInstruction(code, data, startAddress, objData, instructionIndex);
                    instructionIndex++;
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the IL reader provider.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="methodInfo">The MethodInfo object that represents the method to read..</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The ILReader provider.
        /// </returns>
        private static IILReaderProvider CreateILReaderProvider(MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            IILReaderProvider reader = DynamicILReaderProvider.Create(methodInfo);
            if (reader != null)
            {
                return reader;
            }

            return new ILReaderProvider(methodInfo);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks to see if the IL instruction is a prefix indicating the length of the instruction is two bytes long.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The IL instruction as a byte.</param>
        /// <remarks>IL instructions can either be 1 or 2 bytes.</remarks>
        /// <returns>True if this IL instruction is a prefix indicating the instruction is two bytes long.</returns>
        private static bool IsInstructionPrefix(short value)
        {
            return ((value & OpCodes.Prefix1.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix1.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix2.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix2.Value)
                        || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix3.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix3.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix4.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix4.Value)
                        || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix5.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix5.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix6.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix6.Value)
                        || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix7.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix7.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefixref.Value) == OpCodes.Prefixref.Value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The get lookup table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A dictionary of IL instructions.
        /// </returns>
        private static Dictionary<short, OpCode> GetLookupTable()
        {
            // Might be better to do an array lookup.  Use a seperate arrary for instructions without a prefix and array for each prefix.
            Dictionary<short, OpCode> lookupTable = new Dictionary<short, OpCode>();
            FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                OpCode code = (OpCode)field.GetValue(null);
                lookupTable.Add(code.Value, code);
            }

            return lookupTable;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the size of a operand.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operandType">Defines the type of operand.</param>
        /// <returns>The size in bytes of the operand type.</returns>
        private static int GetSize(OperandType operandType)
        {
            switch (operandType)
            {
                case OperandType.InlineNone:
                    return 0;
                case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget:
                case OperandType.ShortInlineI:
                case OperandType.ShortInlineVar:
                    return 1;
                case OperandType.InlineVar:
                    return 2;
                case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
                case OperandType.InlineField:
                case OperandType.InlineI:
                case OperandType.InlineMethod:
                case OperandType.InlineSig:
                case OperandType.InlineString:
                case OperandType.InlineSwitch:
                case OperandType.InlineTok:
                case OperandType.InlineType:
                case OperandType.ShortInlineR:
                    return 4;
                case OperandType.InlineI8:
                case OperandType.InlineR:
                    return 8;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        private object GetData(OpCode code, byte[] rawData)
        {
            object data = null;
            switch (code.OperandType)
            {
                case OperandType.InlineField:
                    data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveField(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineSwitch:
                    data = BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0);

                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
                case OperandType.InlineI:
                    data = BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0);
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineI8:
                    data = BitConverter.ToInt64(rawData, 0);
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineMethod:
                    data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveMethod(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineR:
                    data = BitConverter.ToDouble(rawData, 0);
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineSig:
                    data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveSignature(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineString:
                    data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveString(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineTok:
                case OperandType.InlineType:
                    data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveType(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineVar:
                    data = BitConverter.ToInt16(rawData, 0);
                    break;
                case OperandType.ShortInlineVar:
                case OperandType.ShortInlineI:
                case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget:
                    data = rawData[0];
                    break;
                case OperandType.ShortInlineR:
                    data = BitConverter.ToSingle(rawData, 0);
                    break;
            }

            return data;
        }
    }

    internal class DynamicILReaderProvider : IILReaderProvider
    {
        public const int TypeRidPrefix = 0x02000000;

        public const int MethodRidPrefix = 0x06000000;

        public const int FieldRidPrefix = 0x04000000;

        public static readonly Type RuntimeDynamicMethodType;

        private static readonly FieldInfo fileLengthField = typeof(ILGenerator).GetField("m_length", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        private static readonly FieldInfo IntermediateLanguageBytesField = typeof(ILGenerator).GetField("m_ILStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        private static readonly MethodInfo bakeByteArrayMethod = typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("BakeByteArray", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        private static readonly PropertyInfo dynamicScopeIndexor;

        private static readonly FieldInfo dynamicScopeField;

        private static readonly Type genericMethodInfoType;

        private static readonly FieldInfo genericMethodHandleField;

        private static readonly FieldInfo genericMethodContextField;

        private static readonly Type varArgMethodType;

        private static readonly FieldInfo varArgMethodMethod;

        private static readonly Type genericFieldInfoType;

        private static readonly FieldInfo genericFieldInfoHandle;        

        private static readonly FieldInfo genericFieldInfoContext;

        private static readonly FieldInfo ownerField;

        private object dynamicScope;

        private ILGenerator generator;

        static DynamicILReaderProvider()
        {
            BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            dynamicScopeIndexor = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicScope").GetProperty("Item", bindingFlags);
            dynamicScopeField = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator").GetField("m_scope", bindingFlags);

            varArgMethodType = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.VarArgMethod");
            varArgMethodMethod = varArgMethodType.GetField("m_method", bindingFlags);

            genericMethodInfoType = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.GenericMethodInfo");
            genericMethodHandleField = genericMethodInfoType.GetField("m_methodHandle", bindingFlags);
            genericMethodContextField = genericMethodInfoType.GetField("m_context", bindingFlags);

            genericFieldInfoType = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.GenericFieldInfo", false);
            if (genericFieldInfoType != null)
            {
                genericFieldInfoHandle = genericFieldInfoType.GetField("m_fieldHandle", bindingFlags);
                genericFieldInfoContext = genericFieldInfoType.GetField("m_context", bindingFlags);
            }
            else
            {
                genericFieldInfoHandle = genericFieldInfoContext = null;
            }

            RuntimeDynamicMethodType = typeof(DynamicMethod).GetNestedType("RTDynamicMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            ownerField = RuntimeDynamicMethodType.GetField("m_owner", bindingFlags);
        }

        private DynamicILReaderProvider(DynamicMethod method)
        {
            this.Method = method;
            this.generator = method.GetILGenerator();
            this.dynamicScope = dynamicScopeField.GetValue(this.generator);
        }

        public DynamicMethod Method { get; private set; }

        internal object this[int token]
        {
            get
            {
                return dynamicScopeIndexor.GetValue(this.dynamicScope, new object[] { token });
            }
        }

        public static DynamicILReaderProvider Create(MethodInfo method)
        {
            if (method == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
            }

            DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = method as DynamicMethod;
            if (dynamicMethod != null)
            {
                return new DynamicILReaderProvider(dynamicMethod);
            }

            Type methodType = method.GetType();
            if (RuntimeDynamicMethodType.IsAssignableFrom(methodType))
            {
                return new DynamicILReaderProvider(ownerField.GetValue(method) as DynamicMethod);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public byte[] GetMethodBody()
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            ILGenerator ilgen = this.Method.GetILGenerator();

            try
            {
                data = (byte[])bakeByteArrayMethod.Invoke(ilgen, null) ?? new byte[0];
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException)
            {
                int length = (int)fileLengthField.GetValue(ilgen);
                data = new byte[length];
                Array.Copy((byte[])IntermediateLanguageBytesField.GetValue(ilgen), data, length);
            }

            return data;
        }

        public FieldInfo ResolveField(int metadataToken)
        {
            object tokenValue = this[metadataToken];
            if (tokenValue is RuntimeFieldHandle)
            {
                return FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle((RuntimeFieldHandle)tokenValue);
            }

            if (tokenValue.GetType() == DynamicILReaderProvider.genericFieldInfoType)
            {
                return FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle(
                    (RuntimeFieldHandle)genericFieldInfoHandle.GetValue(tokenValue),
                    (RuntimeTypeHandle)genericFieldInfoContext.GetValue(tokenValue));
            }

            return null;
        }

        public MemberInfo ResolveMember(int metadataToken)
        {
            if ((metadataToken & TypeRidPrefix) != 0)
            {
                return this.ResolveType(metadataToken);
            }

            if ((metadataToken & MethodRidPrefix) != 0)
            {
                return this.ResolveMethod(metadataToken);
            }

            if ((metadataToken & FieldRidPrefix) != 0)
            {
                return this.ResolveField(metadataToken);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public MethodBase ResolveMethod(int metadataToken)
        {
            object tokenValue = this[metadataToken];
            DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = tokenValue as DynamicMethod;
            if (dynamicMethod != null)
            {
                return dynamicMethod;
            }

            if (tokenValue is RuntimeMethodHandle)
            {
                return MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle((RuntimeMethodHandle)this[metadataToken]);
            }

            if (tokenValue.GetType() == DynamicILReaderProvider.genericFieldInfoType)
            {
                return MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(
                    (RuntimeMethodHandle)genericMethodHandleField.GetValue(tokenValue),
                    (RuntimeTypeHandle)genericMethodContextField.GetValue(tokenValue));
            }

            if (tokenValue.GetType() == DynamicILReaderProvider.varArgMethodType)
            {
                return DynamicILReaderProvider.varArgMethodMethod.GetValue(tokenValue) as MethodInfo;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public byte[] ResolveSignature(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this[metadataToken] as byte[];
        }
        public string ResolveString(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this[metadataToken] as string;
        }

        public Type ResolveType(int metadataToken)
        {
            return Type.GetTypeFromHandle((RuntimeTypeHandle)this[metadataToken]);
        }
    }

    internal class ILReaderProvider : IILReaderProvider
    {
        public ILReaderProvider(MethodInfo method)
        {
            this.Method = method;
            this.MethodBody = method.GetMethodBody();
            this.MethodModule = method.Module;
        }

        public MethodInfo Method { get; private set; }

        public MethodBody MethodBody { get; private set; }

        public Module MethodModule { get; private set; }

        public byte[] GetMethodBody()
        {
            return this.MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray();
        }

        public FieldInfo ResolveField(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this.MethodModule.ResolveField(metadataToken);
        }

        public MemberInfo ResolveMember(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this.MethodModule.ResolveMember(metadataToken);
        }

        public MethodBase ResolveMethod(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this.MethodModule.ResolveMethod(metadataToken);
        }

        public byte[] ResolveSignature(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this.MethodModule.ResolveSignature(metadataToken);
        }

        public string ResolveString(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this.MethodModule.ResolveString(metadataToken);
        }

        public Type ResolveType(int metadataToken)
        {
            return this.MethodModule.ResolveType(metadataToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks AbdElRaheim! I will hopefully get a chance to test this code this afternoon.

Comment: Thank you again. I was able to implement your code and achieve what I needed to.

Comment: This is an amazing response. Thank you!!! Can I modify a string based on the metadata token?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't. You would have to parse the code. Look into [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).

Comment: Hmmm....that seems odd (to me). The strings have to be stored in the assembly /somewhere/. Perhaps MS just didn't provide access to that through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* but won't be easy or clean or neat and will probably be difficult to get it working reliably.

You can start with MethodInfo.GetMethodBody() and then parse the binary IL. There are some libraries out there that do that, try [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) for example.